# Underscore each to update collection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to update below collections using underscore but the last win (READ_ONLY become false) overwrite all the previous updates.  Any idea how to fix it please?

```
_.each(availabilities, function(availability, availIndex) {
   _.each(availability.POINTS, function(point, availPointIndex) {
      if(availIndex == 0) {
         point.READ_ONLY = true;
      } else {
         point.READ_ONLY = false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: please show us what `availabilities` is. And make sure to use triple equality `===`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```js
var availabilities = [
  { 
    POINTS:[{READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}]
  },
  { 
    POINTS:[{READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}]
  },
  { 
    POINTS:[{READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}, {READ_ONLY:true}]
  }
]

_.map(availabilities, function(availability, availIndex) {
   _.mapObject(availability.POINTS, function(point, availPointIndex) {
      if(availIndex == 0) {
         point.READ_ONLY = true;
      } else {
         point.READ_ONLY = false;
      }
   });
});

console.log(availabilities);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre>
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
   POINTS: Array[3]
      0: Object READ_ONLY: true
      1: Object READ_ONLY: true
      1: Object READ_ONLY: true
1: Object
   POINTS: Array[3]
      0: Object READ_ONLY: false
      1: Object READ_ONLY: false
      1: Object READ_ONLY: false
2: Object
   POINTS: Array[3]
      0: Object READ_ONLY: false
      1: Object READ_ONLY: false
      1: Object READ_ONLY: false
</pre>
```